TimeFold VariableListener Corruption after Initial Score Calculation
I have a single planning entity (task), and a single genuine planning variable (timeslot).
The planning variable is a resource that is being assigned to a task, with a course grained time range. When a timeslot is assigned, I need to compute the "actual" time range. This is derived from the timeslot, and additional task fields which tell me how to compute the "actual" time range.
We had what we thought was a working VariableListener, but after turning on TRACKED_FULL_ASSERT  I see this error when solving begins:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: VariableListener corruption after completedAction (Initial score calculated):
The entity (Task() assigned to TimeSlot(2024-07-07T08:59:49.956Z to 2024-07-07T09:10:36.337Z: duration PT10M46.381S))'s shadow variable (Task.actualStartTime)'s corrupted value (2024-07-07T18:09:49.927Z) changed to uncorrupted value (2024-07-07T09:00:22.500Z) after all variable listeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.

The "corrupted" value is very different from the original time range, so i'm wondering where it could be coming from.
My Task PlanningEntity:
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "timeslotRange", allowsUnassigned = true)
private TimeSlot timeslot = null;

private Instant actualStartTime = null;

@ShadowVariable(
        sourceVariableName = "timeslot",
        variableListenerClass = TimeSlotStartTimeListener.class)
public Instant getActualStartTime() {
    return this.actualStartTime;
}

private Instant actualEndTime = null;

@PiggybackShadowVariable(shadowVariableName = "actualStartTime")
public Instant getActualEndTime() {
    return this.actualEndTime;
}

My variable listener, TimeSlotStartTimeListener
@Override
public boolean requiresUniqueEntityEvents() { // No idea if this is needed.
    return true;
}

private void updateStartAndEndTimes(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(task, "actualStartTime");
    task.setActualStartTime(someStartTimeMath(task)); // Cant show the actual logic here, but it's a pure function.
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(task, "actualStartTime");
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(task, "actualEndTime");
    task.setActualEndTime(someEndTimeMath(task));
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(task, "actualEndTime");
}

@Override
public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    this.updateStartAndEndTimes(scoreDirector, task);
}

@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Solution> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    this.updateStartAndEndTimes(scoreDirector, task);
}

I have no clue if this is set up correctly. The docs for this are kind of all over the place. They jump between examples, and don't link to any full implementations.
Update 1:
I paid a bit closer attention to the values that cause the exceptions to be thrown. It appears that the shadow values of actualStartTime and actualEndTime are just not what they should be,
So, with an un-itialized solution, this isn't a problem. It's only an issue when I come back to re-solve. So now i'm trying to figure out what could cause the invalid values. The listener update code doesnt actually mutate anything, and is stateless. So i'm pretty stumped how this could happen.
Which to me, likely means the result of the listener is being cached, and some how are being consumed by different tasks/values. No evidence for that yet, but the differences are look like other task actual shadow values.

In all likelihood, the logic you're not sharing is not correct. Typically this happens when the code incorrectly updates the start/end time in a corner case which you did not expect. Debugging this is not easy - step through the var listener code, monitor the state transitions, and hopefully you'll catch your bug that way.

Following up. Turns out it wasnt a bug in the listener, but an issue when setting up the solution. My start/end times were getting mutated, causing the difference. So the exception was accurate. The listener basically couldnt reproduce the values, correctly so.
